# apache error installing trac / wsgi / python

Tags: python, apache, trac, wsgi

I am experiencing a performance issue installing wsgi/trac/python for the first time. We're setting up trac for the first time ever and are having some issues.

As far as I know I've got the components setup in the right places, my Apache is hosted via Wamp, and I will be using MySql 5.x for the database back end.

When I have WSGI disabled in my Apache configuration, Wamp/Apache loads just fine. I can browse to my localhost, phpmyadmin, and so on, no problems.

However, When WSGI enabled, my Apache error log shows the following messages, which keep looping forever it seems, my localhost never responds, nor does my phpmyadmin.

I suspect there is some configuration loop going on, but I couldn't tell you where and need some guidance what to look for.

Is there something else in our Apache configuration that I am missing?

```
ImportError: No module named site 
[Mon Aug 08 10:49:51 2011] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 1 -- Restarting. 
[Mon Aug 08 10:49:51 2011] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7. 
[Mon Aug 08 10:49:51 2011] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.2. 
[Mon Aug 08 10:49:51 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.2 PHP/5.3.5 configured -- resuming normal operations 
[Mon Aug 08 10:49:51 2011] [notice] Server built: Oct 18 2010 01:58:12 
[Mon Aug 08 10:49:51 2011] [notice] Parent: Created child process 3116 
[Mon Aug 08 10:49:51 2011] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7. 
[Mon Aug 08 10:49:51 2011] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.2.
[Mon Aug 08 10:49:51 2011] [notice] Child 3116: Child process is running
```

Thank you...

Comment: there will be other opportunities along the path towards a running trac system, however, I believe I've addressed this one. seems to be that the Apache httpd.conf file requires a block something like this: <IfModule wsgi_module>WSGIPythonHome pathtoyourpythondllandorlibs</IfModule>. this seems to fix the immediate issue; no more thrashing about.

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, I think you should write it up as an answer, not comment, and mark it as accepted.

Comment: The mod_wsgi module does not 'require' WSGIPythonHome to be set. The option exists but on Windows it would be extremely rare that you would need it and think I have only heard of one instance where it was. You question doesn't state clearly whether the looping messages appear immediately on Apache startup, or happen on first request to Trac. You also need to outline if you have multple Python installations on your system.

Answer (score 1):

When we install Python a registry is set by its installer in Windows so wsgi should be able to find Python modules easily without using ConfigurationDirectives.

`HKLM/Software/Python` OR `HKLM/Software/WOW6432Node/Python`

In that registry PythonPath & InstallPath is specified from where it can search for modules, dlls, libs, etc...

When apache module called mod_wsgi can't find these directories the following error occurs

```
ImportError: No module named site
```

So by adding the following line in apache config file we are specifying the directories of dll/lib of Python

```
<IfModule wsgi_module>
WSGIPythonHome pathtoyourpythondllandorlibs
</IfModule>
```

More ConfigurationDirectives of mod_wsgi can be found at
http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives

Comment: Python should be installed for all users and not just the current users on Windows system. Do that and you will not have that problem. Bad idea to rely on WSGIPythonHome on Windows systems as it may not solve all issues around fact that Apache service runs as different user than user that Python was installed for.